# NullPointerException during to Webshpere MQ connection from OSB

Tags: nullpointerexception, ibm-mq, osb

From OSB project I connect to IBM Websphere MQ in BINDING MODE. Sending message asynchronously from the Business Service to MQ queue is working fine but I keep getting a NPE.
    Could someone please tell me what I am doing wrong :) and I advice? I am new to OSB and MQ. The error is below:

```
<AdminServer> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '23' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> 
<<WLS Kernel>> <> <d4c01266a9822b8f:-5e045fa4:154e15afad0:-8000-000000000000222d> <1464087403232> <BEA-000802> <ExecuteRequest failed
 java.lang.NullPointerException.
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.hash(ConcurrentHashMap.java:209)
        at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.containsKey(ConcurrentHashMap.java:836)
        at com.bea.wli.sb.resources.mqconnection.MQConnectionFacade.getMQConnectionContext(MQConnectionFacade.java:70)
        at com.bea.wli.sb.transports.mq.MQTransportTimerListener.timerExpired(MQTransportTimerListener.java:222)
        at weblogic.timers.internal.TimerImpl.run(TimerImpl.java:284)
        at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:550)
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:263)
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:221)
```

Answer (score 0):

A `java.lang.NullPointerException` is being thrown because a `null` object has been passed into the `containsKey(Object)` method on a `ConcurrentHashMap`. See the Javadoc for this:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html#containsKey(java.lang.Object)

You need to work out why the code in `com.bea.wli.sb.resources.mqconnection.MQConnectionFacade.getMQConnectionContext(MQConnectionFacade.java:70)` is trying to lookup an object using a `null` key.  If this is code belongs to Oracle, you might need to engage their Support Teams.